# OpenCV libraries conflicting?

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, ros

I wrote a program in C++ that opens a ROS bag file and export the images using OpenCV.
The image is in different colors because it is YUV422 so I tried to convert it to BGRA and it was successful.

Now I tried to view it with imshow instead of exporting the images to a folder, and I am getting a seg fault. Here is my code:

```
  // Iterate through each message on the topic
  for (const rosbag::MessageInstance& msg : view)
  {
    // Extract the image message
    sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr image_msg = msg.instantiate<sensor_msgs::Image>();

    if (image_msg != nullptr)
    {
      // Convert the image message to an OpenCV Mat object
      cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
      try
      {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(image_msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
        cv::cvtColor(cv_ptr->image, cv_ptr->image, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2);
      }
      catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
      {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        continue;
      }

      // Display the frame
      cv::imshow("Video", cv_ptr->image);

      // Wait for a key press
      if (cv::waitKey(1) == 27) // Esc key
        break;
     }
  }
```

GDB backtrace is logging this error at seg fault:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a176f4 in cv::_InputArray::kind() const () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.2
#1  0x00007ffff7a179bc in cv::_InputArray::size(int) const () at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so.4.2
#2  0x00007ffff7fa65a3 in cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&) () at /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.406
```

Am I correct to suspect the issue has to do with libopencv_highgui library conflicting with the other version, since the seg fault is happening at the `cv::imshow()` function?

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try using a different image for the source and destination of cvtColor.

Comment: For testing try saving the image before `cv::imshow`: `cv::imwrite('image.png', cv_ptr->image)`. It's really hard to guess why `cv::imshow` fails, but if `cv::imwrite` also fail, the issue is probably related to the content of `cv_ptr->image`.

Comment: @Rotem if I comment out the `cv::imshow` it doesn't seg fault.
I even created a `cv::namedWindow("Window",cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)` , but no success.

Comment: @digby280 I tried that too, but no success :/